# how to see the Javascript /html code for my GWT project

Tags: gwt

Is it possible to get the HTML/Javascript code which the GWT compiler generates itslef from the Java code , can i see the javascript code generated against my Java code in GWT,in eclipse

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Look in the web-inf directory. This directory should be in your war directory. You need to build (GWT compile) your project to generate the JavaScript. In dev mode it is run as Java.